# records not written line by line using csvwriter in java

Tags: java

I am using CSVWriter where all the records are written in a single line of text file. please help me in correcting the mistakes in my code.

```
public void parseWritefile()
        {
            try{    

                File file = new File("config.properties");
                FileInputStream fileinput = new FileInputStream(file);
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                prop.load(fileinput);       
                newfile = prop.getProperty("newfile");          
                delimit = prop.getProperty("delimiter");
                delimiter = delimit.charAt(0);          
                fileinput.close();

                Compare Writefile = new Compare();
                List<String[]> fnllist = Writefile.comparecollec();                                 
                CSVWriter writer=new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(newfile),delimiter,'"',"\n");
                log.debug("Records are written");
                writer.writeAll(fnllist);               
                writer.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                 {
                    log.error("File not found");
                } 
            catch (IOException e)
                 {
                    log.error("IO exception");  
                }
        }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Post a complete, minimal example reproducing the problem. Don't rely on unknown files containing unknown values. Hard-code the list of rows you want to write.

Comment: Thanks I got the right output.... I have made a mistake in my other class comparecollec...found it and resolved....